# unit testing controller action with call multi Mediator.Send command

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, integration-testing, mediator

I have a controller action that use multi mediator, but I don't know to how can I write unit test for this action. help me please

```
var userObject = await _mediator.Send(new CreateUserCommand(contract),                
            cancellationToken);
var productObject = await _mediator.Send(new CreateProductCommand(contract), 
           cancellationToken);
var userProductObject = await _mediator.Send(new GetUserProductQuery(contract), 
           cancellationToken);
```

Comment: What behavior do you want to test? If you only want to test whether the mediator is called with the proper arguments you can just mock it.

Comment: I want to write one unit test for 3 commands to check results and after that, check action result. Can I write this unit test? Is it a correct unit test? @Peter Bons

Comment: If you want to validate the working of the commands, you should write unit tests for each of them seperately. Otherwise it seems an integration test is more what you are after.

Comment: Thank you, How can I write integration test for this action? @Peter Bons

Comment: That is a bit out of scope for SO, here are some links to get started [1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/testing?view=aspnetcore-6.0), [2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-6.0), [3](https://www.guru99.com/unit-test-vs-integration-test.html)